# Store not up to date on component load - nuxt.js

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

having a problem with my Vuex store and loading a component. I have a category/product style page structure in my nuxt app, and I am trying to simply move from the category to the product page. But when getting to the product page, consistently getting "Cannot read property 'url' of undefined" error.

This is happening because my store only seems to be getting updated after the product page component is loaded, even if using async/await.

Here is my category component:

```
<template>
  <div class="container mb-5">
    <div class="page-title-container py-3">
      <h1 class="border-bottom border-dark">{{ currentRange.name }}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row product-list">
      <div v-for="product in categoryData.products" class="col-12">
        <a @click="setProduct(product)" class="d-flex flex-row mb-3 py-3 border product">
          <div class="img-container overflow-hidden d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center px-2">
            <img class="img-fluid" :src="product.icon.url"/>
          </div>
          <div class="attributes d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
            <span class="pb-2 border-bottom mb-2 mr-2"><strong>{{ product.name }}</strong></span>
            <span>{{ product.rental_rate.price | currency('£') }} per week</span>
            <span class="btn btn-outline-primary rounded-0 btn-sm mt-3" :class="(configurable(product) === 'Bundle') ? 'w-75' : 'w-50'">{{ getButtonText(product) }}</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Slugify from 'slugify';

    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {}
        },
        async asyncData(context) {
            let currentCategoryId = context.store.state.app.currentCategory.id;
            let {data} = await context.$axios.get('https://api.current-rms.com/api/v1/products?q[m]=or&q[g][0][6_eq]=' + currentCategoryId + '&q[g][1][6_start]=' + currentCategoryId + ',&q[g][2][6_end]=,' + currentCategoryId + '&q[g][3][6_cont]=,' + currentCategoryId + ',');
            return {categoryData: data}
        },
        methods: {
            productSlug(product) {
                return Slugify(product.name, {lower: true});
            },
            configurable(product) {
                let type = this.$store.getters.getCustomFieldListValue(product.custom_fields.product_type);
                return type[0].name;
            },
            getButtonText(product) {
                return (this.configurable(product) === 'Bundle') ? 'CONFIGURE' : 'VIEW';
            },
            async setProduct(product) {
                await this.$store.dispatch('setProduct', product). then(() => {
                    this.$router.push({name: 'products-slug', params: { slug:this.productSlug(product)} });
                });
            }
        },
        computed: {
            currentRange() {
                let currentCategory = this.$store.state.app.currentCategory;
                if (currentCategory == null) {
                    return this.$store.state.app.previousCategory;
                }

                return currentCategory;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

My Product component:

```
<template>
    <div class="container product-page">
      <div class="img-container">
        <img class="img-fluid" :src="product.icon.url"/>
      </div>
      <div class="attributes d-flex flex-column justify-content-start">
        <span class="pb-2 border-bottom mb-2 mr-2"><strong>{{ product.name }}</strong></span>
        <span>{{ product.rental_rate.price | currency('£') }} per week</span>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
              product: {}
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.product = this.$store.state.app.currentProduct;
        }
    }
</script>
```

And My Store:

```
export const state = () => ({
  app: {
    currentProduct: {}
  },
});

export const mutations = {
  SET_CURRENT_PRODUCT(state, payload) {
    state.app.currentProduct = payload;
  }
};

export const actions = {
  async setProduct({dispatch, commit}, product) {
    await commit('SET_CURRENT_PRODUCT', product);
  }
};
```

I have tried all sorts including setTimout in the category page to make sure the store is updated with the currentProduct before moving to the product page.

Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks